# Decrypting font string used by XLoadFont

Tags: linux, fonts, x11

I am trying to figure out what the varying pieces of a font string represent. For example:

```
-adobe-helvetica-medium-r-normal--11-80-100-100-p-56-iso10646-1
       ^ font name      ^ r=regular, o=italic
                 ^ medium or bold
```

I labeled the few I use and know, but what is the rest used for?

Basically, I am hoping to learn the format so I can dynamically create these strings to load new fonts.

I attempted to locate something in Google, but I am obviously using the wrong search terms. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Side note: this is a pretty strongly deprecated API; supposed to use fontconfig, freetype, and something like Pango these days. The simplest is Cairo's toy API, if you aren't using a modern toolkit (GTK, Qt, etc.) that already does this properly.

Comment: I know, I hate doing this, but it is an old app that I didn't write and I really don't want to rewrite, just trying to spruce up a few things.

Comment: fair enough, just adding it to the question for future passers-by. it's pretty simple to point Cairo at an X drawable, without using gtk or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [X Logical Font Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_logical_font_description), available at http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/XLFD/xlfd.html